# Add here buttons in Experience Editor don't match placeholder

Tags: experience-editor, placeholders, components

I'm having some oddball things happening with my Sitecore environment's experience editor. We have a pretty basic layout - one single placeholder named 'content', where we can add multiple components/renderings.

We have a single Master Layout that has a standard `@Sitecore.Placeholder("content")` and we have the placeholder defined in `/sitecore/Layout/Placeholder Settings` where the placeholder key matches 'content' and we have a limited amount of controls inside here, and all of that appears to be working fine.

I created a new blank page (using the master layout), and I add datasource items (using the appropriate templates) and update my presentation details with the appropriate controller renderings, I am able to see all of my components like expected.

The moment I open the experience editor to add new components, I click the "Add new components" icon, and my `+ Add here` tags are displayed above my modules in an "empty placeholder" which is also named "content", and I can't add components between my other components.

[image]

It's as if the items weren't added to the placeholder appropriately. Some pages appear to be just fine, with (Add Here) icons displaying correctly between modules, and some don't. I'm trying to figure out how the experience editor is determining where a placeholder really is and how it's deciding where to add the (Add here) icons.

One thing I noticed is that I'm unable to move/delete the components I've added in the Content Editor.
Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might already have checked these though, but if not this would be helpful:

1. Did you add the renderings in the Allowed Controls? If not, you should add the renderings in the Allowed Controls of that placeholder present in the Placeholder settings.  Screenshot below for reference.:
   [image: Allowed Controls]
2. Check the "Editable" checkbox is checked for the renderings you have created, which you want to add/move/delete from Experience Editor mode. Screenshot below for reference:
   [image]

If you have already checked the above points and the issue persists, can you try changing the name of the placeholder to anything else, other than "content" as you have mentioned, sometimes it all works fine but at times not. So there might be a chance of conflict due to presence of same named placeholder already, causing the ambiguity. I think we usually have default placeholder named "content" in Sitecore.

Comment: I did review alot of the other SO articles that mentioned [X] Editable, and all of my renderings are in the "Allowed controls" already. The issue isn't that I can't add the controls, it's just that the Add here controls sometimes don't show up between my existing controls, and sometimes even on a blank page, I will add a control, then try to add a second one, but the "Add here" only shows up ABOVE my existing control, and I can't add anything below it - so what ends up happening is the controls always add above the existing controls. It's a pretty weird experience.

Comment: I will try to rename the placeholder and see if that changes anything. The problem is we already have around 100 pages with multiple components and it will be an exercise (or a custom development task) to rename all of the placeholders in an attempt to change all existing content.